# How do I aggregate event data using pubsub with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am building a small booking calculator with backbone.js which mostly responds to user inputs based on  manipulating static sets of data. I have the application carved up into separate components like:

1. Packages
2. Calendar
3. Ticket
4. TotalCostView

The last component `TotalCostView` is the most important. It outputs the final cost of the booking *based on event data published by the other components* mentioned in the above list. Now I am using a simple jQuery pub sub implementation as my global eventbus:

```
  /* jQuery Tiny Pub/Sub - v0.7 - 10/27/2011
 * http://benalman.com/
 * Copyright (c) 2011 "Cowboy" Ben Alman; Licensed MIT, GPL */

  var o = $({});

  $.subscribe = function() {
    o.on.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.unsubscribe = function() {
    o.off.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.publish = function() {
    o.trigger.apply(o, arguments);
  };
```

This works pretty well expect for one thing: I cannot access the aggregated data I need to calculate the final `totalCost`.

So when I publish an event like so:

```
var SelectListView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
      'change': 'pkgSelected'
  },

  pkgSelected: function(ev){
     $.publish('pkg/changed', selectedPkg);
  },

});
```

I subscribe to it like so:

```
$.subscribe('pkg/changed', _.bind(this.updatePackageAmount, this));
```

I get the current selected package data. The problem is that I am unable to get the data that other parts of the application are publishing like:

```
$.publish('car/selected', selectedCar);
$.publish('numTickets/changed', ticketData);
```

I am unable to aggregate all the data in one place for calculation like:

```
  updatePackageAmount: function(ev, numTickets, travelCost, currentDate){ // I need the data passed in as parameters to be always fresh

    var totalCost = parseInt(cost * numTickets, 10) + parseInt(travelCost, 10);
    this.render(totalCost);
  },
```

How do I aggregate data without one component having knowledge of another component? Should I use some kind of sensible global App object on which to store this common shared data? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: For the sake of consistency, you might consider using an object with `Backbone.Events` mixed in as your event bus instead of a jQuery object.

Comment: Could you show me how? And also tell me how that would solve my problem with data aggregation?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily help with the aggregation bit, which is why I didn't put it in an answer. Purely a suggestion: since Backbone has its own event semantics, it might be less cognitive overhead. See [this page](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) for an example. You can also just use the global `Backbone.Events` object as an event bus since v0.9.9.

Answer (score 3):

Since Backbone v0.9.9, the global `Backbone.Events` object has had the
[Backbone events behavior](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) mixed in, so you can
use that object as your global event bus. It's a pretty common pattern to have
some kind of global event bus to tie all your behavior together. Without one,
I think you're left with creating an ownership hierarchy of some kind where
higher-level objects bubble up events from their children and trigger events
from higher levels on their children.

I think the event bus approach might be easier to deal with in a small application:

```
var SelectListView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
      'change': 'pkgSelected'
  },

  pkgSelected: function(ev){
     // : is commonly used for event namespacing in Backbone, but feel
     // free to keep using /
     Backbone.Events.trigger('pkg:change', selectedPkg);
  },

});

// Your total view
var SomeOtherView = Backbone.View.Extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var _this = this;
        // If you use listenTo, the event listener will automatically be
        // disabled when your view is removed
        this.listenTo(Backbone.Events, 'pkg:change', function(selectedPkg) {
            _this.selectedPkg = selectedPkg;
        });
    }
)};
```

You could even use a [`Backbone.Model`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) for
storing the results of all your options: your controller could listen for
changes on `Backbone.Event`, set the appropriate fields on the model itself,
and your view could then listen for change events on the model and re-render
itself as appropriate.

Anyway,
[Backbone.Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette)
provides a suitable global application object ([`Marionette.Application`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md)) which
might work for your case (in addition to a lot of other really nice components
for building Backbone apps).

Comment: Since I am using a static immutable data set, none of the models are actually changing. It's user selecting a different package in the above case. So what fields would I set in my model? 

Also how would I aggregate data from multiple events across components? A click event sends data and then that data is lost the next time the user selects a package from a dropdown? How do I keep hold of the old click data all the time?

Comment: The model doesn't necessarily have to represent your data, but it can be a useful way to store UI state.

Comment: aah! you mean like if I stored ui state as {'selected': true}?

Comment: Right. You could have a model with fields like `pkgSelected`, `numTickets`, etc. that your UI can change. When you change the fields with `Model.set`, a change event is triggered (like `change:pkgSelected`) that your total views can listen to and re-render if they need to.

Comment: hmm...will give that a try Wyatt